# Tracing and debugging in OCaml

Tags: debugging, ocaml, trace

What do you use for tracing and debugging in OCaml?

For debugging I tried ocamldebug and the Emacs plugin.

For tracing I want to be able to print the data constructor of every variable.
An example using Camlp4 is shown here: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/tutorial-camlp4/tutorial007.html#toc52

```
   type colour = Red | Green | Blue
   let print_colour =
     function
       Red -> print_string "Red"
     | Green -> print_string "Green"
     | Blue -> print_string "Blue"
```

Comment: There's no built-in way to print values of a user defined type, but there are some external projects that solve the problem in various ways.  See this previous SO question page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518752/is-there-a-way-to-print-user-defined-datatypes-in-ocaml

Comment: For tracing, the toplevel is the easiest way, if you can do your experiments in it (works well for data structure debugging, not so well for I/O).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ocamldebug` works fine when you can use bytecode.

If you want to debug a native code application, there is a [patch by Thomas gazagnaire](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=5487) on Mantis that allows to step line by line in the OCaml program using gdb. Parts of this patch should be integrated in the next version of OCaml (3.13 or 4.00).

Currently, however, there is no way to print OCaml values, but another patch is coming, using GADT's to define a generic printer function for any type.

Comment: Hi, what is the state of gdb/lldb support, as of 2015?

Comment: What's a bytecode file? I tried everything and `ocamldebug` says "not a bytecode file".