# How to convert a polymorphic value to a string?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, static-typing, parametric-polymorphism

I am actually looking for a function with a signature like `'a -> string` which converts a given polymorphic type into a string. I already thought about something like

```
let func elem = match elem with
| int -> string_of_int elem ...
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7518752/124319

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to match on types in OCaml and this is a feature! Such restriction leads to [parametricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism).

In simpler words, if a function, `f`, has for type `'a -> string`, its type promises to work on any possible types, past and future. In other words, the function `f` cannot make any hypotheses on the content of its argument.

The only honest possibility is thus to do not try to read anything from the argument and simply returns a string, for instance

```
 let f _x = "x?"
```

Possibly, we can read some global states with a function `g`

```
let f _x = g ()
```

for instance

```
let counter = ref 0
let f _x = incr counter; string_of_int !counter
```

Comment: Also, types don't exist at runtime anyway. But values can be explicitly tagged with type information using a variant, e.g. `type t = Int of int | String of string`, which can of course then be matched on.